# What should I set Capybara.app to when testing a nodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, express, cucumber, capybara

I've seen like a million of times:

If you are not using Rails...

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
Capybara.app = MyRackApp
```

But if you want to test a node.js express v4 application what is "MyRackApp"?

Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capybara.app is for testing a Rack app in-process.](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#setup) Your app isn't a Rack app, so you have to test it out of process. See ["Calling remote servers" in the Capybara documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#calling-remote-servers). Briefly,

```
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist # or :selenium if you prefer slower tests ;)
Capybara.app_host = 'http://your.app'
```

And don't set `Capybara.app`.